# How do people check how many characters there are added/removed when editing question/answer?

Tags: support

when sombody edits a question, he always leaves like "added 70 characters in body" in the explenation.

I don't think everybody counts the amount of characters they add.

how do they know how many characters have been added? Is it witten somewhere or do they just count?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the default edit message when you don't provide one. (2k rep users and post owners can skip that field.)